# BuildConfig.DEBUG и minifyEnabled

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-sdk

есть код, который обернут в проверку Дебага.

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    $мой_код 
}
```

и в релизной сборке у меня включено

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
```

вопрос:
в итоговом, обфусцированном, релизном коде будет ***$мой_код*** или он будет вырезан, т.к. неиспользуемый?

UPD
в комментах подсказали как декомпилировать. поэтому теперь прошу помощи разобраться в результатах:
Исходный код:

```
  Log.e("!!!", "1")
      if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.e("!!!", "2")
     }
  Log.e("!!!", "3")
```

Итоговый *apk

```
.method public onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
    .registers 3

    invoke-super {p0, p1}, Landroidx/fragment/app/q;->onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V

    const p1, 0x7f0b001c

    invoke-virtual {p0, p1}, Ld/h;->setContentView(I)V

    const-string p1, "!!!"

    const-string v0, "1"

    invoke-static {p1, v0}, Landroid/util/Log;->e(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I

    const-string v0, "3"

    invoke-static {p1, v0}, Landroid/util/Log;->e(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I

    return-void
.end method
```

Я правильно понимаю, что `if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)` не попал в релизный код?

Comment: а что мешает проверить?

Comment: @Эникейщик незнание "как это проверить")

Comment: Собрать релиз, декомпилировать и посмотреть. Если понимаете синтаксис smali, то можно открыть ваш APK/AAB/AAR и посмотреть прямо в студии

Comment: > Я правильно понимаю, что if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) не попал в релизный код? //// Да, правильно поняли. Было бы куда наглядней ставить не восклицательные знаки, а осмысленные слова, тогда совсем очевидно было бы